# Problems with special characters after R version 4.1.3

Tags: r, rstudio

I am experiencing problems with special characters (accents, ¨, and so on) with the newer versions of R.

I am running a large dataset that has denominations of traits in either French or German, with lots of special characters. This dataset is coupled with a Shiny app for extracting different kinds of summary result tables, graphs and so on.

Everything worked fine up to and including R version 4.1.3. However, with the most recent R-versions the special characters are "messed up", both in the Rstudio script files, and in the outputs of my shiny app.

The problem must have to do with the R-version and not Rstudio, since I updated to newer Rstudio versions and the problem did not appear, as long as I keep running the older 4.1.3. version of R with it.

I found a few recent posts describing similar problems on here. All recommended changing the text encoding options, but this does not seem to work in my case.

I changed the text encoding in the "Global options" of Rstudio, i.e. to UTF-8.
I also tried a few others, but so-far to no avail.

Any insight is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you on Windows? There was a major change in R 4.2.0 for text encoding: https://blog.r-project.org/2022/11/07/issues-while-switching-r-to-utf-8-and-ucrt-on-windows/index.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response! Yes I'm on Windows. Thanks for the link, I'll check it out!

Comment: Hi again! I read the article you shared, and I understand that my problem must certainly have to do with that major change in text encoding. However,  I still could not figure out how to find a practical solution to the issues I am facing. Sorry, it is probably due to me being a noob in this kind of things. Do you have by any chance some other links or more concrete suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: Use RStudio to re-save your files in with UTF-8 encoding (File -> Save with Encoding...) and see if that helps with the issue. Also make sure that there aren't any character conversions going on elsewhere with things like `iconv()`.